# Asignar el valor de una columna a un valor infinito

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo valores infinitos en mi dataframe, pero en vez de sustituir esos valores por Nan, 0 u otro valor, me gustaría que en cada fila ese valor inf, se sustituyese por el valor que tenga en cada fila una columna específica. Pongo un ejemplo:

| Jugador | Minutos | Minutos por centro |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Andrés | 120 | 42 |
| Juan | 80 | inf |
| Ramón | 60 | inf |
| Pedro | 198 | 33 |

¿Con qué código puedo, que al valor inf de Juan se le asigne el valor de sus Minutos (80), y que al valor inf de Ramón se le asigne el de sus minutos (60)?

Es decir, que siempre, que en este dataframe en la columna 'Minutos por centro' o cualquiera otra columna haya un inf, se le asigne el valor de la columna Minutos que tenga cada jugador.

He intentado con df.replace(np.inf, df[df['Minutos']], inplace=True) y de otras maneras pero no consigo solucionarlo.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando `df.loc` debes seleccionar las filas que necesitas cambiar (para lo cual puedes usar una condición como `df["Minutos por centro"]==np.inf`) y la columna que quieres cambiar `"Minutos por centro"`, y asignarle el valor deseado, leido de la otra columna.

Es decir:

```
df.loc[df["Minutos por centro"]==np.inf, "Minutos por centro"] = df.Minutos
```

resultado:

```
  Jugador  Minutos  Minutos por centro
0  Andrés      120                42.0
1    Juan       80                80.0
2   Ramón       60                60.0
3   Pedro      198                33.0
```

## Ampliación

Si el dataframe tiene varias columnas que puedan contener infinito, por ejemplo como el siguiente:

```
  Jugador  Minutos  Minutos por centro  Otra columna  Otra más
0  Andrés      120                42.0           inf      20.0
1    Juan       80                 inf          10.0       inf
2   Ramón       60                 inf           inf       inf
3   Pedro      198                33.0           inf      10.0
```

y se quieren reemplazar todos los infinitos del dataframe por el valor que aparezca en la columna Minutos, la solución más breve y rápida es utilizar [DataFrame.where()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html#pandas.DataFrame.where), en este caso así:

```
df = df.where(df!=np.inf, df.Minutos, axis=0)
```

El resultado sobre el dataframe de ejemplo anterior sería:

```
  Jugador  Minutos  Minutos por centro  Otra columna  Otra más
0  Andrés      120                42.0         120.0      20.0
1    Juan       80                80.0          10.0      80.0
2   Ramón       60                60.0          60.0      60.0
3   Pedro      198                33.0         198.0      10.0
```

Comment: Pero @abulafia, y si en vez de una columna, fuesen una una gran cantidad de columnas,  y quiero seleccionar que todos los valores inf de todas las columnas del dataframe, esos inf se sustituyan por el valor `Minutos`?

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Así ya si está solucionado!! Mil gracias @abulafia. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hola Manuel un gusto en saludar.

Bueno primero definimos el código del del dataframe para verificar mejor las acciones.

en este caso utilicé la definición de infinito (**np.inf**) como infinito de la biblioteca Numpy

```
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>import numpy as np
>>>df = pd.DataFrame({'Jugador': ['Andrés', 'Juan', 
                  'Ramón','Pedro'],
                  'Minutos': [120,80,60, 198],
                  'Minutos por centro': [42,np.inf,np.inf,33]})
```

el resultado del frame

```
>>>df

Jugador Minutos Minutos por centro
0   Andrés  120 42.0
1   Juan    80  inf
2   Ramón   60  inf
3   Pedro   198 33.0
```

Nótesé, la columna 'Minutos por centro' utilizando un **np.inf** se define como un **float64** y la columna 'Minutos' se define como un **int64**, lo resalto entre asteriscos (*)

```
>>>df.dtype

Jugador               object
Minutos               int64
Minutos por centro    float64
dtype: object
```

Pero para tener las dos columanas con igual dtype convertimos la columna minutos a float64

```
>>>df['Minutos']=df['Minutos'].astype(np.float64)
```

Ahora sí estarías las dos columans como float

```
>>>df.dtypes

Jugador                object
Minutos               float64
Minutos por centro    float64
dtype: object
```

Ahora el dataframe está definido así

```
>>>df

Jugador Minutos Minutos por centro
0   Andrés  120.0   42.0
1   Juan    80.0    inf
2   Ramón   60.0    inf
3   Pedro   198.0   33.0
```

Así como @abulafia definió

```
>>>df.loc[df["Minutos por centro"]==np.inf, "Minutos por centro"] = df.Minutos
```

luego de aplicar la solución de @abulafia que da el frame así

```
Jugador Minutos Minutos por centro
0   Andrés  120 42.0
1   Juan    80  80.0
2   Ramón   60  60.0
3   Pedro   198 33.0
```

Ahora me tomé la molestia de adecuar los datos para poder hacer la sustitución y agregar un plus si llegas a luego hacer aritmética con los tiempos, donde el método Timedelta es genial

```
>>>conversionm = pd.Series(df['Minutos'])
>>>conversionmpc =pd.Series(df['Minutos por centro'])

>>>def conver(x):
>>>    return pd.Timedelta(pd.offsets.Minute(x))

>>>conversionm = conversionm.apply(conver)
>>>conversionmpc = conversionmpc.apply(conver)
>>>ndf = pd.concat([df['Jugador'],conversionm,conversionmpc],axis=1)
>>>ndf

Jugador Minutos Minutos por centro
0   Andrés  0 days 02:00:00 0 days 00:42:00
1   Juan    0 days 01:20:00 0 days 01:20:00
2   Ramón   0 days 01:00:00 0 days 01:00:00
3   Pedro   0 days 03:18:00 0 days 00:33:00
```

Ves que pudieras enriquecer un como el dataframe con el método **Timedelta**, lo interesnte de esté método es que pudes luego mas fácil mostrar minutos, segundos etc de una manera más facil

y si quisieras de nuevo tenerlo en un formato "números netos"

```
>>>ndf = pd.concat([df['Jugador'],conversionm.dt.seconds/60,conversionmpc.dt.seconds/60],axis=1)
>>>ndf

Jugador Minutos Minutos por centro
0   Andrés  120.0   42.0
1   Juan    80.0    80.0
2   Ramón   60.0    60.0
3   Pedro   198.0   33.0
```

Espoero haber contribuido de manera positiva a la solución

saludos